# Transferring focus between focus traversal policy providers

Tags: java, swing, focus

I have several custom panels arranged in a basic BoxLayout, on which I have set a `SortingFocusTraversalPolicy` (and also set `setFocusTraversalPolicyProvider(true)`, in order for the policy to take effect).

The custom focus traversal works perfectly within each custom panel, but when you tab out of the last component in the custom panel, focus goes to the first component in that same panel, rather than the first component in the next custom panel.

How would I go about "chaining" the focus from one custom panel to another?

Comment: No sure, but does removing isFocusTraversalPolocyProvider do anything? Have you consider providing a transversal policy for the parent container?

Comment: can you show some snippet of it being constructed and it getting displayed?